# Initializing state in React without constructor

Tags: reactjs

I have a class component as shown below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Aux from "../../../hoc/Auxilary/Auxilary";
import ComponentDetails from "./SideBarLayoutDetails";
import DropDownDetails from "../UI/DropDown/DropDownDetails";
import Row from "../UI/Row/Row";
import "./Layouts.css";
import Dropdown from "../UI/DropDown/DropDown";
import Calendar from "../UI/Calendar/Calendar";

class SideBarLayout extends Component {

    state = {
        isActive: Array(DropDownDetails.length),
        isDateActive: false,
    }


    DropDownArrowHandler = (index) =>
    {

    }

    render()
    {
        const calendar = this.state.isDateActive ? <Calendar />:null;

        return <Aux>
                <div className = "SideBar-Central">
                                <Row Elems = {ComponentDetails.TopHeaders.elements} 
                                Container = {ComponentDetails.TopHeaders.container}
                                />
                                <Dropdown Elems = {DropDownDetails[0].DateFilter} 
                                Container = {DropDownDetails[0].DateFilterContainer}
                                />
                                {calendar}
                </div>
        </Aux>
    }
}

export default SideBarLayout;
```

I want to initialize `this.state.isActive` in a loop fashion like this:

```
const initializedvalue = DropDownDetails.map(elem => elem.active);
```

and then use this `initializedvalue` to assign to `this.state.isActive`.

But I want to do this just when the component renders in the screen. What is the best way to do so? Should I use `constructor`? I don't prefer it as I get a warning using `super(props)`. Please let me know the best way to do so. My end goal is to have a `this.state.isActive` array ready to be used in making the decisions about rendering the screen components.

Comment: that is not how react works... period. I suggest you read react documentation on how local state works vs props vs global state (redux for example)

Comment: Also forEach is a void function... Please read the docs you have all info there.

Answer (score 2):

First, `forEach` does not return any value as it is a void function. So try map function instead. This will return elements for which active is true (assuming `active` is a `boolean` type property in `elem`)

`const initializedvalues = DropDownDetails.map(elem => elem.active);`

Next, if you want to use this to set `this.state.isActive` after render, run it in `componentDidMount()`. Its a lifecycle function that runs after the initial render is done.

Comment: I don't want to use `componentDidMount` because it will setup the values after first render cycle... rather I want to use something like `ComponentWillMount`. My end goal is to use this initialization before component mounts and not after.

Comment: Then use ComponentWillMount().